# MySQL sorting by product of an operation?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to SORT MySQL results by the product of an operation on 2 fields

eg: `field1*field2=product`

MySQL: `SORT BY product ASC;`

Comment: Really basic SQL questions like this should be asked on our sister site [so]. I've requested that your question be moved there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is nothing sophisticated to it. You can use aliases in `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT 
  field1*field2 AS product
FROM
  tableName
ORDER BY product
```

Comment: Thanks @Mchl I did not realize that an alias could be used :)